# Merging SharePoint with Word

Tags: list, word

I am merging a SharePoint list with Word to create letters.  If a field in SharePoint has no data it show in Word as the name of the field see example below

```
Ms. Jane K. Tompkins , AICP
[Title]
South Miami
[Section]
6130 Sunset Drive
[Address2]
South Miami, Florida 33143-5093
```

How do I get it to drop out the fields that have no information, like?

```
Ms. Jane K. Tompkins , AICP
South Miami
6130 Sunset Drive
South Miami, Florida 33143-5093
```